# What is the integral of $\sqrt{\tan x}$

Tags: calculus

I just need to know why is my method wrong:
Let $I=\int\sqrt{\tan x} dx$, let $\tan(x)=t^2$ then, \begin{align*}&\sec^2(x)dx=2tdt\\
\implies&(1+\tan^2(x))dx=2tdt\\
\implies &dx=2tdt/(1+t^2)\end{align*}

So \begin{align*}I &= \int t\cdot \frac{2t}{1+t^2} dt\\
  &= \int\frac{2t^2}{1+t^2}dt\end{align*} which can be solved easily. Is this method correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: "which can be solved easily": why don't you proceed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's flesh out @QuantumApple's hint. With $\tan x=t^2$,$$\begin{align}\int\sqrt{\tan x}dx&=\int\frac{2t^2dt}{1+t^4}\\&=\int\frac{1}{2}\left(\tfrac{1}{1-\sqrt{2}t+t^{2}}+\tfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}t+t^{2}}-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}-2t}{1-\sqrt{2}t+t^{2}}+\tfrac{\sqrt{2}+2t}{1+\sqrt{2}t+t^{2}}\right)\right)dt\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan(\sqrt{2\tan x}-1)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\arctan(\sqrt{2\tan x}+1)\\&+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln\left|\frac{\tan x-\sqrt{2\tan x}+1}{\tan x+\sqrt{2\tan x}+1}\right|+C.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it.

Answer (score 3):

If $\tan(x) = t^2$ then $1 + \tan^2(x) = 1 + t^4$ (and not $1 + t^2$).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.